# How do I be good?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

In the ad wherein [Steve Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Martin) promotes his [master class](https://youtu.be/ZwcDvw70-n0) I note that, at some point, he asks this:

**How do  I be good?**

Is that usage standard in the English-speaking world? Or is it just some kind of private joke of his? Is this phrase interchangeable with

How do I become good?

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: Yes it's a joke. No, *be* does not take do-support like that in Standard English. But most importantly: no, it is not actually equivalent to "how do I become good". That's the beauty of it. It doesn't just do something random for a cheap laugh. It does something very specific to bring across a meaning you can't quite bring across otherwise. Steve Martin is quite a master at that, if you're not familiar with his works.

Comment: The relevant bit of the ad starts about 10 seconds into the video at the second link; the actual line is at 0:19.

Answer (score 2):

"Be good" often has the special meaning of "behave well/properly".

In that sense, it's hard to know how to ask the question Martin is asking, because "How am I good?" would not have that meaning. Probably most people would ask "How will I be good?" or "How should I be good?"But I don't find "How do you/I be good?" strange in that context.

However, looking in various online corpora, I find hardly any examples of it.

Comment: The exact version as cited does sound "odd" - but doubtless given it's being said by Steve Martin, I'm sure the scriptwriters knew that perfectly well, and were effectively "playing it for laughs".  The sequence *"You must be good", "I don't know how to do that. How do I be good?"* makes it sound a *little* better, but if instead he'd asked *How **can** I be good?* no-one would think anything of it (but of course no-one would chuckle at the quirky phrasing).

Comment: I don't think that's the meaning of "be good" Martin is using here. It sounds more like he means "be good *at comedy*" (or even "be funny").